# How to install a scr model in ltspice

Tags: ltspice, scr, model

I have downloaded an scr model file from this website and pasted it in the same folder as that of my .asc file.
But ltspice still shows unknown subcircuit called for the scr present.
What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: Are you trying to install a **subcircuit** or a **model**? These are two very different things in SPICE. Maybe you should show us the first non-comment line in the file you downloaded.

Comment: As @ElliotAlderson says, it looks like you downloaded a **model**, but used a symbol with the `X` prefix, which calls for a **subcircuit**. However, I doubt that it is a model, since SCRs are, usually, subcircuits, so more details are needed. And, pelase, be more clear, the clearer you are, the clearer the solution can be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a symbol, and link it with the model name AND path.

[image]

Comment: Did you see the image I just added? Right click and select "edit attributes" in the SYMBOL file, not the schematic you're using it in.

Comment: It is still showing the same error

Comment: There is a similar attribute in the schematc you're using it in that may need to be set. It doesn't have a path if I remember right.